# WP7: Add Supported Cultures in C#

Tags: windows-phone-7, localization

Is there any option to add `<SupportedCultures><SupportedCultures>` dynamically in Windows Phone???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's worth noting that this metadata is read by the marketplace, so you would *want* to resubmit your application if you add support to additional locales.